# Running VS Code with the root privileges not work anymore in ubuntu linux

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am using visual studio code with this command in ubuntu linux
Running VS Code with the root privileges (not recommended)

```
sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
```

I always use this in command line because normal way visual studio code does not allow me to save my code updates.
but today

```
sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
```

this code does not work anymore when i try to run it in command line, it does not open visual studio code anymore.
Giving click in vscode icon run normally but it does not allow me to save anything, it asked me retry as sudo, i do and it does not do nothing, i can not enter as sudo in this way.
any suggestions on how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the wrong solution to your issue. The proper solution is to move your source code to a folder that your normal non-root account has read/write access to instead, so that you don't need to elevate your access to save or update your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which part in ubuntu linux should i save my projects? documents?

Comment: Somewhere under your `/usr` folder. Root should only be used for systems operations that are restricted to prevent accidental or malicious changes to your system, and nothing else. You should find a good tutorial or book on *nix (Unix/Linux) that teaches the basics of the operating system - a Google search should be able to locate one for you. (For future reference, this site is for programming (code) related questions. Not being able to start an application as root isn't a programming question. A more suitable site for this question would be [ubuntu.se]. There's also [su].)

Comment: Thank you very much, what i do not like of vscode in ubuntu, it is that ask me to be root in order to save my updates, i should try to move the folder proyect or not use IDE, i like to work with command line a lot, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 9):

**best way (recommended):**

just use this :
`sudo code "your-directory" --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox`

**for example to open** `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, **use**:

`sudo code /etc/nginx/nginx.conf --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox`

> vscode will create files where you open terminal because of :
> `--user-data-dir='.'`

**another way (not recommended):**

use `sudo chmod -R 777`

> But it will give the full access of your project directory to all
> users on the machine

You can use chown on the project directory to own it only for yourself

```
cd /location
sudo chown your_username your_project_directory
```

**Example:**

let's say I have a directory called `project1` in my `/var/opt` location and my user name is tom.

```
cd /var/opt
sudo chown tom project1
```

Comment: thanks, had the same problem,  "sudo code /lol --user-data-dir='.' --no-sandbox" worked for me

Comment: In my linux box, I had to do `xhost local:root` before to properly see VSC window contents.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem

`sudo code myfile` stopped working sometime in July/August 2021

I use VS Code as my standard code/text editor and that includes editing different system config files where I need root privileges to edit.

A simple way to fix this problem is to add an alias in the config-file for your terminal. (`~/.bashrc` if you have bash as your shell)

I call the alias "sucode"

```
alias sucode='sudo code $1 --user-data-dir='"'"'/root/.config/Code - OSS/'"'"' --no-sandbox'
```

Save the file and restart your shell (`source ~/.bashrc`) and from now on you enter `sucode myfile` instead of `sudo code myfile` whenever you need to edit a text file with root privileges.

Please note the path to the root account's user data folder for VS Code.

On my Arch-system the folder where VS Code stores it's user data is called "Code - OSS" and for the root account the complete path to this folder is:

```
/root/.config/Code - OSS/
```

It's good to check to see if your installation of VS Code has the same path. If it hasn't, you have to modify the alias-command accordingly.

In my opinion it's not such a great idea to specify the user-data-dir as the dot-folder (".") because then VS Code will clutter every folder, where you happen to be when you call VS Code, with dozens of root owned folders.

Comment: I did this, and it almost works. VSCode starts with the filename followed by "Visual Studio Code [Superuser]" in the title bar, but the window remains white. The Code data path is right, there are a bunch of files there which were created when I started code with sucode. I looked in the logs /root/.config/Code/logs and I can't see any errors. This is a Raspberry Pi / Debian Bulldog 64 bit and Code runs fine non-root. It's like Code can't write to the display.  I shut off hardware acceleration in Code and Chromium but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, if I have to edit anything that requires administrative access, I'll normally use Vim to do so instead of VSCode.

Security aspects aside, I completely agree with the answer by glob about using `/root/.config/Code` instead of `'.'`. Or, create a directory for this somewhere else...

As implied, some people want to edit nginx/Apache files or perhaps Linux configuration files such as /etc/hosts as a Visual Studio Code Superuser.
If you were to use `'.'` it will create the entire "Code" directory structure inside of the working directory (/etc or /etc/nginx, etc.) in a dispersed fashion. That's at least 15 directories including Backups, CachedExtensions, Code Cache, plus files. This is not desired in a place such as /etc or any other directory that requires administrative access. Not only is it messy, but is a potential security concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you configure the sshd in wsl with root access, you can use vscode with remote ssh.

create a `/usr/local/bin/sucode` as below

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# wsl host name configured in /etc/wsl.conf
ssh_profile=root@wsl-ubuntu
# function to encode string to url string
urlencode() {
  python -c 'import urllib.parse, sys; print(urllib.parse.quote(" ".join(sys.argv[1:])))' "$@"
}
# get absolute path
path_string=$(realpath $@)
# get url of path
path_url=$(urlencode $path_string)
# if is file
[ -f $1 ] && code --file-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+$ssh_profile$path_url"
# if is folder
[ -d $1 ] && code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+$ssh_profile$path_url"
```

and make sure it has the correct ownership and permission.

Now you can use

`sucode dir[/file]`